# I want to split a single dataframe column into multiple oclumns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 1 column and 5776 rows. I want to move every 76 rows into a new column so I am left with 76 columns and 76 rows. How do I do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpWAa.png)

Answer (score 3):

This might be the transpose of the matrix you want, and if so you can do wide_df = wide_df.T

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':np.random.rand(5776)})

wide_df = pd.DataFrame(df['column1'].values.reshape((76,76)))
print(wide_df)
```